# Vertex AI Search is querying all the documents in a datastore. Is this a bug? or a feature?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, vertex-ai-search

I've been using Google Vertex AI Search & Conversation for the past few weeks, and I've noticed a significant change recently.

Initially, when I made a query, it would only display the most relevant results. If the query was irrelevant, it would show no results at all. For instance, consider this example showing a completely irrelevant result before the change:

[image: Vertex AI before the change]

However, starting from March 27th (though this might have begun earlier, I just didn't catch it), whenever I create a new app, it seems to search through the entire document base instead. Here's an example using the same entirely irrelevant query on a new app and data store created today:

[image]

I would love to get back to the state where irrelevant queries yielded no results. Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

I have tried to create new data stores and new apps with different configurations with no results.
My data is an structured JSONL file with several columns